# next-auth - my session comes back as undefined when trying to create GraphQL context? - NextAuth / NextJs

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using `next@13.4.7` with `next-auth@4.22.1`. I am using the new `/app` directory. I have an api route for my GraphQL endpoint.

```
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from "@as-integrations/next";
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { HttpContext } from "@/server/context";
import { schema } from "@/apollo/schema";

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
});

const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server, {
  context: async (req, res) => {
    return await HttpContext.init(req, res);
  },
});

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  return handler(request);
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  return handler(request);
}
```

My `HttpContext` file has an `init` method to wire everything up.

```
  static async init(req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) {
    const session = await getServerSession(options);
    console.log("session", session);
    return new HttpContext(req, res, session);
  }
```

When I hit the endpoint `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session` I get the session and all the session data back in the browser, but at the same time, the session variable above will log out as `undefined`. I want to attach my user session to the context, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you calling the graphql server from your React component(s)?